# Problems with images in frontend

Tags: magento2, php

We have problems with images in frontend side.

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ImageFactory::create() must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\Product, array given, called in ...

If change `"return $this->imageFactory->create($data);"` in this method for `"return false;"` - the error disappears. But we have a new problem in different sections:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function toHtml() on boolean in  ...

This error after `getImage(...)->toHtml` and `getImageUrl(...)->toHtml`

I debbug params, what get methods **getImage** and **getImageUrl**. Emptiness gets there. All sections where there is a withdrawal of goods do not work on the site. The images are displayed correctly in the admin panel, but in frontend, I think the problem is in the pictures.

What can help for solve this problems? (Magento 2.2.5, php 7.1, mysql 5.7)

Answer (score 0):

.phtml file

```
<a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getProductUrl($_item) ?>" class="product photo product-item-photo">
            <?= $this->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
</a>

getImage() Function in Block File

 <?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class file_name extends Template
{
    protected $imageBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $contextImage,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->imageBuilder = $contextImage->getImageBuilder();
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getImage($product, $imageId, $attributes = [])
    {
        return $this->imageBuilder->setProduct($product)
            ->setImageId($imageId)
            ->setAttributes($attributes)
            ->create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but we have a problem in all templates where catalog products are displayed. You definitely don't need to edit the code. Everything works correctly on the main site. We have difficulties deploying a test copy for development.

Comment: In case if the image is not showing on all pages the possible cause your Static Contents are most likely out of date. You can regenerate your static contents with this command on your server from your Magento 2 root folder. Note that you may or may not need to delete files from pub/static/frontend

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <locale>